# how to pass the bool values to next view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, boolean

I have 2 `VC` :

`FirstVc` in that i have one textfield `NamesTF` . 
`secondVC` i need to check whether in  `FirstVc` the `NamesTF` have values are not. If values is available my `bool` value have to come `True` .If values is not available `bool` value have to come `False`
My code :

`FirstVc` :

```
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "DashBoard", bundle: nil)
        let destinationVc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC")

if NamesTF.text == "" {

 SecondVC.NameAvailable = false
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVc, animated: true)
}

else 
{
 SecondVC.NameAvailable = false
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVc, animated: true)
}
```

In my `SecondVC`:

```
 var NameAvailable = false

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

if NameAvailable == true {

// print the name

}
else {

// no name availble //false
}
}
```

What i am doing wrong. Can any one help me out.

Thanks ~

Comment: It still doesn't make sense. You are setting the `Bool` in `SecondVC` and pushing `destinationVc`. Set the bool in `destinationVc` like this `destinationVc.NameAvailable = true`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: @Tushar Sharma i want to check with bool . not in passing the string

Comment: @david the concept of passing values never change either bool, string , array etc.

Comment: Use delegation concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code should be something like this.
The mistake you are  doing in your  code is that you are assigning `false` value to the `Bool` variable `NameAvailable` in your **secondVC**, so whatever calue weather `true` or `false` you are passing from **firstVc** is overriding to `false`  every time in the **secondVC**

**First VC**

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "DashBoard", bundle: nil)
        let destinationVc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondVC")

if NamesTF.text == "" {

 destinationVc.NameAvailable = true
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVc, animated: true)
}

else 
{
 destinationVc.NameAvailable = false
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVc, animated: true)
}
```

**In Your Second VC**

```
var NameAvailable = Bool()


override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

if NameAvailable == true {

// print the name

}
else {

// no name availble //false
}
```

Try it it will definitely work :)

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing the 'destinationVc' so your code should be like:

```
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "DashBoard", bundle: nil)
    let destinationVc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"SecondVC")
    destinationVc.NameAvailable = !(NamesTF.text == "")
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVc, animated: true)
```

Comment: I am getting error like `instance member 'NameAvailable' cannot be used on type 'secondVC`

Comment: Where you have defined 'CircleNameAvailable' ? In the SecondVC you defined 'NameAvailable'.

Comment: Sorry `var NameAvailable : Bool?` Like that  i declared in My `secondVC`

Comment: @Abhishek Thapliyal  `NameAvailable` should be   `bool` value or `string`  in my `seconsVC`

Comment: it should be Bool @david

Answer (score 1):

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "DashBoard", bundle: nil)
let destinationVc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"SecondVC") as! SecondVC
destinationVc.NameAvailable = !(NamesTF.text == "")
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVc, animated: true)
```